# The riddle and its affixes

Tags: riddle, word, affix-riddle

> My prefix is an increase, a flowing unit, and an acid
> My infix, with different hearts, can be friends, fruits, or emotions
> My suffix can make castles, storms, and even paper
> My all is not the word you discovered, for that is only my name
> **What am I?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are

> **&**, or an ampersand

Your prefix is

> **amp**, as in amplify, [Ampere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ampere) and [AMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adenosine_monophosphate).

Your infix is

> **pers**, as in pe**e**rs, pe**a**rs and pe**u**rs, which means fears in French.

Your suffix is

> **sand**, as in sandcastle, sandstorm and sandpaper.

Comment: Waited a bit for that edit, great job!